# Improving speed and data efficiency with javascript calculator.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, performance

I'm building a javascript calculator (with jquery mobile) for simplifying routine calculations in microscopy.  I'm looking to create more efficient code and would love any input...  I don't expect anyone to dig through the whole thing, but here is the link to the program for reference: http://www.iscopecalc.com

(the javascript for the calculator is at http://www.iscopecalc.com/js/calc.js )

The calculator basically consists of about 12 inputs that the user can set.  Using the values received from these inputs, the calculator generates values for about 15 different parameters and outputs the results in the display.  Currently, whenever the state of an input changes, I bind that change event to a quick function that writes the value for that input to a cookie.  But the meat of the program comes with the "updateCalc()" function which reads the values from all of the inputs (from stored cookies) and then recalculates every one of the parameters to be displayed and outputs them. I've coped just that function here for ease of access:

```
function updateCalc(){

readValues();       //load current calculator state into cookies
var data = $.cookie();  //puts all cookie data into object

var fluorData = fluoroTable[data['fluorophore']];  //fluorophore data taken from table at the end of the file depending on chosen fluorophore
    var fluorem = fluorData['fluorem'];
    var fluorex = fluorData['fluorex'];
var cameraData = cameraTable[data['camera']];   //camera data taken from table at the end of the file depending on chosen camera
    var campix = cameraData['campix'];
    var chipWidth = cameraData['chipWidth'];
    var chipHeight = cameraData['chipHeight'];
    var chipHpix = cameraData['chipHpix'];
    var chipVpix = cameraData['chipVpix'];


var RefInd = data['media'];         //simple variables taken directly from calculator inputs
var NA = data['NAslider'];
var obj = data['objective'];
var cammag = data['cameraRelay'];
var CSUmag = data['CSUrelay'];
var bin = data['binning'];

var pinholeRad;
var FOVlimit;
var mode;

if (data['modality']=='widefield'){     //FOVlimit, pinholeRad, and CSU mag will all depend on which modality is chosen
    FOVlimit = 28;
    pinholeRad = NaN;
    mode = 'Widefield';
    CSUmag = 1;
}
else if (data['modality']=='confocal'){
    if (data['CSUmodel']=='X1'){
        pinholeRad = 25;
        if(data['borealis']=='true'){
            mode = "Borealis CSU-X1";
            FOVlimit = 9;
        }
        else {
            mode = "Yokogawa CSU-X1";
            FOVlimit = 7;
            CSUmag = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (data['CSUmodel']=='W1'){
        mode = "Yokogawa CSU-W1";
        FOVlimit = 16;
        pinholeRad = data['W1-disk']/2;
        CSUmag = 1;
    }
}

//These are main outputs and they depend on the input variables above

var latRes = 0.61 * fluorem / NA;
var axRes = 1.4 * fluorem * RefInd / (NA*NA);
var BPpinhole = 1000 * pinholeRad / (obj * CSUmag);
var AU = BPpinhole / latRes;
var totalMag = obj * cammag * CSUmag;
var BPpixel = 1000 * campix * bin / totalMag;
var samples = latRes / BPpixel;
var pixperpin = BPpinhole * 2 / BPpixel;
var sampLit = 1000 * FOVlimit / (obj * CSUmag);
var coverage = FOVlimit * cammag / chipHeight;
if (coverage < 1) {
            chipUsed = coverage;
            FOV = sampLit;
        }   
        else {
            chipUsed = 1;
            FOV = sampLit * chipHeight / (FOVlimit * cammag);   
        }
var sampWaste = 1 - FOV / sampLit;
var imgpix = 1000 * FOV / (chipVpix / bin);

//function goes on to update display with calculated values...
}
```

It works ok and I'm generally pleased with the results but here's what I'd like advice on:

Each of the input variables only really affects a handful of the outputs (for instance, a change in input #3 would only really change the calculation for a few of the outputs... not all 15), however, my function recalculates ALL outputs everytime ANY of the inputs are changed, regardless of relevance...  I've considered making a giant If-Then function that would selectively update only the outputs that would have changed based on the input that was changed.  This would obviously take a larger amount of code, but I'm wondering if (once loaded) the code would be faster when using the calculator, of if it would just be a waste of my time and clutter up my code.

I'm also wondering if storing inputs in cookies and reading values back from cookies is a reasonable way to do things and if I should maybe make a global variable instead that stores the state of the calculator.  (the cookies have the added benefit of storing the users calculator state for later visits).

I'm pretty new at this stuff, so any and all comments on how I might improve the efficiency of my code would be greatly appreciated (feel free to just link to a page that I should read, or a method I should be using for instance...)

if you've made it this far, thanks for your time!!

Comment: Just a random question: Does this actually need to be optimized? Based on the computations in the code you've provided, there doesn't seem to b any heavy math here, so even if you managed to reduce the workload a bit by computing only 3 or 4 fields at a time, you may not gain much. I took a quick look at the JS file you linked, and yes cookie may not be the best solution (cookies are just one long string that gets parsed). And the DOM manipulation would maybe be where I focus my attention.

Comment: Does the app feel slow? Usually it is good to worry about performance when it actually becomes a problem, but maybe that is opinion.  Not saying to ignore performance... but sometimes it is hard to grasp what will be slow before you see it, computers are pretty good at math, and if you dont have a O(n2) algorithm or worse, or some slow I/O, it is probably OK.  And yes @syazdani is right, DOM manipulation can be very slow... once made the mistake of updating the DOM in a game loop.... not good.

Comment: Yup, definitely the DOM. Don't reconstruct the display-content over and over again. Keep the labels and contents separate wherever possible, and try to reduce the number of CSS property manipulations after the fact by using CSS class add/remove wherever possible. if (modality===widefield) => set css class on root element, use stylesheet to control the visibility rather than element by element for example.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not hard core math here, and I don't think it feels slow.  Certainly any modern computer would be able to chew threw this code in milliseconds.  So I guess it's really a broader question about where I might focus my attention as a developing programer.  Thanks for the tips on rebuilding the display over and over again... I'll definitely clean that up.

Comment: And depending on the frequency of change events, you may want to look into debouncing and throttling your event handlers as well. A good JS implementation: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: thanks for taking a look syazdani.  I'll read about throttling...